# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Records has no column named (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Records() VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

my activity code

```
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        db.addRecord(new Record(Price,Item,Details, currentDateandTime));
```

my DB CODE

```
package budgetreport.com.budgetreport;

   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Records_Item Purcashes";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_RECORDS = "Records";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "Price";
private static final String KEY_ITEM = "Item";
private static final String KEY_DETAILS = "Details";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "Date";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECORDS + "("
            + KEY_PRICE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ITEM + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT" + KEY_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RECORDS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new contact
public void addRecord(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_PRICE, record.getPrice()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_ITEM, record.getItem()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, record.getDetails()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_DATE, record.getDetails()); // Contact Phone Number

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_RECORDS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
// Getting single contact
public Record getRecord(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RECORDS, new String[] { KEY_PRICE,
                    KEY_ITEM, KEY_DETAILS, KEY_DATE }, KEY_PRICE + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Record record = new Record(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return record;
}
// Getting All Contacts
public List<Record> getAllContacts() {
    List<Record> contactList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            record.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            record.setDetails(cursor.getString(2));
            record.setDate(cursor.getString(3));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(record);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
// Getting contacts Count
public int getRecordsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, record.getPrice());
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, record.getDetails());
    values.put(KEY_DATE, record.getDate());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_RECORDS, values, KEY_PRICE + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(record.getPrice()) });
}
// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_RECORDS, KEY_PRICE + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(record.getPrice()) });
    db.close();
}
}
```

and this the error

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Records has no column named Date
>   E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Date=צ Details=צ Item=מ Price=0
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Records has no column named Date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Records(Date,Details,Item,Price) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:896)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:507)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1371)
>                         at budgetreport.com.budgetreport.DatabaseHandler.addRecord(DatabaseHandler.java:64)
>                         at budgetreport.com.budgetreport.Report.onClick(Report.java:205)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create Table query you have miss the comma in after KEY_DETAILS column name.here's right query for create table.

```
 String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECORDS + "("
        + KEY_PRICE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ITEM + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL/Sqlite "Date" is a predefined function, you should either use different name for date column like "str_date" or use **"["** for same name. eg: **"[Date]"**

While inserting value, use this:

```
values.put("[" + KEY_DATE + "]", record.getDate());
```

Same while creating table:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECORDS + "("
            + KEY_PRICE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ITEM + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT" + "[" + KEY_DATE + "]" + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

This error up in two situation

**1st. Solved in upper answer by @sagar_Jathveda (that have answer solved sign)**
and some have do other mistake
**other mistake solution is below**

Here is Solution :
i facing same issue and now i fix it

we you want to make database app then
you have two java classes
first for  Parameters
`Params.java` , and other is `Contact.java` where  we make constructors, getter&setter etc.

`Param.java` Class Code Below: **(see Error in Line:5 and 6)** and fix that reference

```
package com.andro.background.crud_db.param;

public class Params {
    public static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DB_NAME="contacts_db"; //(-_-)check this, My mistake was "contact_db" , i write wrong name so it shows error
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="contacts_table"; // Right is "contact_table", this kinda error in your code

    //key of our table in db
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE="phone_number";
}
```

(check this error in upper code)
if you do same mistake then your error will be like this below code

```
2020-02-03 02:57:24.432 10705-10705/com.andro.background.cruddb E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts_table has no column named phone_number
2020-02-03 02:57:24.434 10705-10705/com.andro.background.cruddb E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=sunnykanumber phone_number=9090909090
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts_table has no column named phone_number (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts_table(name,phone_number) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.andro.background.cruddb.data.MyDbHandler.addContact(MyDbHandler.java:62)
        at com.andro.background.cruddb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```